# Adding two 9-bit numbers with carry in AVR Assembler

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, avr, atmega, atmel

I need to add two **9 bit** numbers using the instructions ADD and ADC. The numbers are stored in **R21:R20** and **R23:R22** (MSB: LSB) pairs of registers. The registers should not be overwritten.

The micro-controller I am using is an AtMega16A which has a max register size of 8 bits.

Below is my solution. I would really appreciate if someone could share their feedback.

```
ldi r24, 0 ; result LSB
ldi r25, 0 ; result MSB
clr r26 ; helper
mov r24, r21 ; move MSB part of first number to r24
add r24, r23 ; sum it with MSB part of second number
adc r25, r26 ; add overflow to r25
add r24, r20 ; add LSB part of number 1 to r24
add r24, r22 ; add LSB part of number 2 to r24
; result is R25:R24
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like a 16-bit addition, the only difference is that it won't overflow.

The basic code for 16-bit addition is:

```
add r20, r22 ; A:LSB += B:LSB
adc r21, r23 ; A:MSB += B:MSB + LSB carry
```

If you want to keep intact your initial registers, you have to copy one value:

```
mov r24, r20
mov r25, r21
add r24, r22
adc r25, r23
```

If your MCU supports the `movw` instruction (the ATmega16A does), you can move in one instruction:

```
movw r24, r20 ; r24:r25 = r20:r21
add  r24, r22
adc  r25, r23
```

Comment: ATmega16A has MOVW instruction. Copy first operand to register R24 and R25 can be done by only one instruction `movw R24, R20`